# iOS 7 UITableViewController navigation like iOS 6

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, user-interface, ios7, uinavigationbar

in iOS 6 my navigation in my UITableViewController looks like this:

[image]

and in iOS 7:

[image]

How can I mimic the iOS style?  I would use an image, but the text for each cell is different length.

Comment: You could use an image that scales to the size of the text so [text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:FONT_NAME size:FONT_SIZE]].width would give you the size of the text and then add some padding. Add the text to the button titleLabel then add it as a subview. Or live with how ios7 looks, having the look of an ios6 app on ios7 will stand out like a sore thumb and wouldn't be praised.

Comment: Please re consider what you are trying to achieve, as the documentation says " (...) the overall advice remains the same: First, focus on redesigning the app for iOS 7. Then—if the redesign includes navigational or structural changes—bring these changes to the iOS 6 version as appropriate (...)" [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/SupportingEarlieriOS.html)

Comment: Yes, agree with both regarding iOS 7 however, I am doing  this for a customer and they want the iOS 6 look. LOL, I am sure once it ships I will be chaining it back to iOS 7.

Comment: @LilMoke What do you care? You get more work. :D

Answer (score 1):

You should use an image with a resizeable caps. This way, your image will stretch in the middle and fit any text.